# Could not find guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar

Tags: gradle, guice, quarkus

Could not find guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar on a newly initialized quarkus project, not sure why we see this error. Source code is available here - https://pastebin.com/9qaTfb7D

```
./gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'foo-receiver'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar (com.google.inject:guice:4.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your dependencies that would transitively bring in Guice? FWIW, using Guice in Quarkus makes no sense, Quarkus already provides a dependency injection container based on CDI (which is mostly a superset of AtInject).

Comment: I commented out everything, id 'io.quarkus' seems to be causing this issue

Comment: I can't rule that out, but it is _very_ unlikely. With Maven, I'd do `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where that dependency comes from -- I don't know about Gradle, but this page looks like it might help: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

Comment: @Rpj I've created an empty project using the quarkus starter with the same dependencies as you paste bin without errors, can you provide a reproducer ?

Comment: not clear what do you mean by a reproducer, do you want me to attach the project as well. is it something to do with the JDK, we use 14.0.2

Comment: A reproducer generally is a project which can be run in other machines to reproduce the issue @Rpj.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this and was able to get past that error by modifying the generated `settings.gradle` file. I moved `mavelLocal()` to the end of the list of repositories for pluginManagement.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    plugins {
        id "${quarkusPluginId}" version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}
```

In my particular use case, I'm trying to create a subproject in a multi-project Gradle build. Not sure if that's related to this or not.